# Duplicated and HTML-Encoded JSON Schema Code in Webflow/CMS

Tags: html, json, content-management-system, webflow

I'm facing a problem on my website where JSON Schema code, when posted on a specific page in Webflow/CMS, gets duplicated onto many other pages, and the code appears in HTML-encoded format for e.g.,

```
&#39;@context&#39; 
&quot;name&quot;
```

rather than displaying as normal JSON code. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and do you have any suggestions on how to prevent this unwanted duplication and HTML encoding?

Web dev team tried multiple options but no success